# Can you program a key fob for a 2019 Navigator to work for a 2004 Navigator?

Tags: ford, fob, navigator

There’s nothing wrong with the key I have now, I was just wondering if this is possible.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

No.

The 2019 navigator as far as I know uses PROX remotes (keyless entry and keyless start) with a fcc id of: M3N-A2C940780

The 2004 navigator uses a completely different style of keyless entry remote with a fcc id typically of CWTWB1U331 or CWTWB1U511.

If you want to try, go to your 2004 Navigator.
Insert key and turn ignition ON to OFF 8 times ending in the ON position. Your locks will lock then unlock. At this time hit the lock button on the 19 Navigator remote. If it programs you will hear the locks lock/unlock again. Then turn key off.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Navigator (of either flavor), but most vehicles I've dealt with will forget ALL remotes programmed for it when you go to program new remotes. If your old remote works, you go to program in the 2019 remote, I'll bet the 2004 remote will be lost and need to be reprogrammed. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes that is true, Fords in general indeed do drop the old remote codes not present during the programming I listed out above. Long as you successfully learn a remote while doing it anyway. If you have multiple remotes you need to hit the lock button on each remote before turning the key off.

Comment: I guess my real point here is, don't be surprised and be ready to program the first remote when you try to do the new one. Shouldn't be difficult, since you're already in the process anyway, lol.

Comment: Thank you for responding! 

I want to know for sure the new key will definitely work before I spend the money to buy it. Do you think it would be that easy? If not, is there anything I can do to this car to get the new key to work?

Comment: No, a 2019 navigator Prox fob will never work on a 2004 Navigator Ignition system or Keyless entry so do not waste the money. It was more of a theoretical exercise that would have failed. What is it you actually want for the 2004 Navigator,  a key to start it? a remote to unlock the doors? You didn't happen to mean a 2014* navigator did you? Even then, the 2019's fob is not the same so it would not work.

Comment: We just bought it a month or so ago and the key and the key fob are separate. I’m used to fob being on the key. Also, my mom broke the top off the key so we can’t put it on the keyring with the fob anymore. It’s just a pain in the ass having to fish in my pockets for one or the other. I saw you can buy a key on Amazon that works for the 2004 Navigator but I was curious if I could get one with the Lincoln logo on it. I can just get the other one.

Comment: The FCC ID on the key I have is CWTWB1U551. Can I still get a key that is CWTWB1U331?